# trigger not working on constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger on `accounting` table.. When the parent `enclosure` row is deleted all child rows in `accounting` are deleted..

A trigger on `accounting` delete from `invoice` - but it doesn't work if the parent row in `enclosure` is deleted? It only works when deleting from `accounting`

## db structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enclosure` (
`id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `enclosure`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounting` (
`id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `enclosure_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `accounting`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `enc_id` (`enclosure_id`), ADD KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `accounting_delete_invoice` AFTER DELETE ON `accounting`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `invoice` WHERE id=OLD.invoice_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
`id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `invoice`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `accounting`
ADD CONSTRAINT `accounting_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `accounting_ibfk_17` FOREIGN KEY (`enclosure_id`) REFERENCES `enclosure` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

## data

```
INSERT INTO `enclosure` (`id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `invoice` (`id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `accounting` (`id`, `enclosure_id`, `invoice_id`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
```

## requests

```
DELETE FROM `enclosure` WHERE id=1; # row in `invoice` not deleted
DELETE FROM `accounting` WHERE id=1; # row in `invoice` deleted
```

Comment: At [Restrictions on InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html) they basically say: "Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers". It might be your case.

Comment: @RyanVincent, could a trigger on `enclosure` that deletes all child rows in `accounting` trigger a new trigger on `accounting` which deletes all rows in `invoice` ?

Comment: I agree with @Álvaro González, but beside that your setup looks peculiar. If you delete an Account it will trigger a delete of the invoices for that account that will cascade delete the Accounts that will trigger ...

Comment: Both the trigger and the CASCADE DELETE are defined for the accounting table, not the enclosure table. I am unclear as to why you are using a trigger instead of  a CASCADE DELETE.

Comment: `invoice` is not explicit a child to `accounting`.. It can be created without a record in `accounting`